# Selenium - block "redirect blocked" for chromedriver

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I execute a test through selenium after one click it shows me "Redirect blocked". I found how to disable it for popups (--disable-popup-blocking), but can not figure out how to do it for "Redirect blocked".

Comment: show the code and error messages , welcome to SO!! please read [mcve] before posting and follow it in every next question

Comment: there is no error message (it just not redirect you) and code is useless as well becouse it's propably just a metter of chrome option or different thing that I should set but have no idea what exactly is it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
```

Comment: Could you please share some details about the issue you are facing lilke browser version, webdriver version etc

Comment: Selenium Webdriver version: 3.4.0
ChromeDriverVersion 80.0

Comment: Works perfecto !!!